# error with automator applescript "do shell script" call (file not found) yet command line with same command works

Tags: applescript, automator, ssh

I have a simple automator app that runs a simple script. It uses `ssh` to open a file on the local machine, `MachineA`, with an app on the remote machine, `MachineB`, and logs the ssh call.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    repeat with fn in input
        set fn to POSIX path of fn
        set fn to "/Volumes/MachineA" & fn
        set fn to "\"/usr/bin/open -a /Applications/Preview.app " & fn & "\""
        set cmd to "ssh -x MachineB.local " & quoted form of fn
        do shell script "echo " & cmd & " >> ~/cmd.log"
        do shell script cmd
    end repeat
end run
```

The log output is:

```
ssh -x MachineB.local "/usr/bin/open -a /Applications/Preview.app /Volumes/MachineA/Users/<USER>/Documents/<FOLDER>/<FILE>.pdf"
```

When I use the app to open a file (drag & drop), an error is thrown.

[image: error message]

However, if I copy the output in the log file to the command line, success, the file is opened on the remote machine. Why the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but it looks like you have too many levels of quotes there. You manually put double-quotes around the command to be run over ssh (in the `set fn to "\"/usr/bin/open ... & "\""` line), and *then* use `quoted form of fn`, which adds *another* level of quotes. It looks fine when you `echo` it, but that's because the shell parses & removes one level of quotes before passing to the `echo` command.

Also, if the file path contains spaces or other funny characters, those need to be quoted (but *only* that path part, not the entire command). Try this instead:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    repeat with fn in input
        set fn to POSIX path of fn
        set fn to "/Volumes/MachineA" & fn
        set fn to "/usr/bin/open -a /Applications/Preview.app " & quoted form of fn
        set cmd to "ssh -x MachineB.local " & quoted form of fn
        do shell script "echo " & quoted form of cmd & " >> ~/cmd.log"
        do shell script cmd
    end repeat
end run
```